# How can I load some JSON into my web application with JavaScript and select a random word?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a file that I have saved as words.json that is a large list of words, ordered alphabetically and by length.

They are structured like this:

```
{"3":["ace","act","add","ado","ads"], "4":[...], ...}
```

(For brevity I added the ellipsis)

How can I load the JSON to the page and select a random word on the list?  Do I need jQuery?  What should my function look like?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're asking how to do it without refreshing the page, and if the JSON structure is in a file on the server, you'd make an XHR (AJAX) request to fetch it, then you'd use `JSON.parse()` to parse it. You don't need jQuery, but if you already have it loaded, it does have its own API for making XHR requests.

Comment: ...Whether or not you use jQuery for this, I recommend learning how to make XHR requests directly. It's really pretty simple.

Comment: Depending upon the size of the word list and whether you want to do anything else with these words client-side, there might well be a good argument for doing this server-side.  Why would you want to send the whole list down to the client only to have the client choose just one of them?

Comment: Could you please go into more detail as to why you added the ellipsis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function getRandomWord(jsonStringListOfWords) {
    var words = JSON.parse(jsonListOfWords);

    var MAX_LENGTH = Object.keys(words).length;
    var wordLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_LENGTH) + 1;
    var wordIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[wordLength].length) + 1;

    return words[wordLength][wordIndex];
}
```

Where it first chooses the length of the word randomly, then one of those words from the list of words of that length.  This, as ScottSauyet pointed out in the comments, will not give you an even distribution between all words of varied length.

Here's an example of an algorithm which gives an even distribution for all words, regardless of length:

```
function getRandomWordEvenDistribution(jsonStringListOfWords) {
    var words = JSON.parse(jsonListOfWords);

    var numWords = 0;
    for (var x in words) {
        numWords += words[x].length;
    }

    var wordIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numWords);

    for (var x in words) {
        if (wordIndex >= words[x].length) {
            wordIndex -= words[x].length;
        } else {
            return words[x][wordIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

As far as actually loading the JSON, if you are willing to use jQuery, it has a very nice method called `$.getJSON()`, which you can use to grab the JSON string from your server.

Comment: And how would I load the file into that?  Just putting in the file name in the parameters isn't working.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams it depends where the JSON is stored.  Is it on the client?  Is it on a server?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams you can use the jQuery.getJSON(): `$.getJSON('word.json', function(data) { // do stuff with data });`

Comment: This technique may or may not be what you want for a random selection.  Even if there are only a few 23-letter words, they are as likely to get picked as the five-letter ones by this algorithm.

Comment: Right now the JSON is on the client, I might move it later but for now it's just in the same directory as the other JS files.

Comment: That's technically on the server, if you just put it where all the other .js files are.  If you're running a static file server, trying visiting `http://server.tld/myjsonfile.json` and see if you get that json file.  If you do, you can use that for the `$.getJSON()` request.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks for pointing it out, added an algorithm that should do even distribution.

Comment: @Mash: Definitely a nicer distribution!

Comment: So would it be something like `$.getJSON('word.json', getRandomWord(data));`?  Or did I understand the function incorrectly?

Comment: Just `$.getJSON('http://server.tld/word.json', getRandomWord)`.  Then inside of `getRandomWord()` instead of just `return`, you can insert the word into the DOM, or do whatever you want with the word.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working still, I'm getting "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." Any ideas?
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @CassidyWilliams: That sounds like a browser not wanting to do AJAX from the local file system.  Do you have a local web server you can test on?  Or a remote one you can move your code to easily?  If not, some browsers allow you to override this policy.

Comment: I did it a really hacky way and just stuck in the JSON data into my JS file for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Also @Mash this line in your solution isn't necessary `var words = JSON.parse(jsonListOfWords);` because then you're just parsing it twice!  You could do it just `var words = jsonListOfWords;` or not make a new variable at all.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams I had assumed you were working with a JSON string, not a JavaScript object.  I'll just rename the parameter to indicate it expects a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with Mash's algorithm (I made two minor fixes to it, and updated that answer with them.)  You're right about the `JSON.parse` being unnecessary with jQuery's `getJSON`.  It's **[running on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/itaxif/2)**:

```
var words = (function() {
    var wordList, numWords;

    return  {
        load: function(data) {
            wordList = data;
            numWords = 0;
            for (var x in wordList) {
                numWords += wordList[x].length;
            }
            words.random = function() {
                var wordIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numWords);
                console.log(wordIndex);

                for (var x in wordList) {
                    if (wordIndex >= wordList[x].length) {
                        wordIndex -= wordList[x].length;
                    } else {
                        return wordList[x][wordIndex];
                    }
                }
            };
        },
        random: function() {
            return undefined; // or throw exception?  // not initialized yet
        }
    };
}());
var print = (function() {
    var $console = $("#console");
    return function(msg) {
        $console.text($console.text() + "\n" + msg);
    };
}());

$("#random").click(function() {
    print("Random word: " + words.random());
});

print("Random word before load: " + words.random());

$.getJSON("http://jsbin.com/ukaxec/2/js")
    .then(words.load)
    .then(function() {print("Random word after load: " + words.random());});
```

The `$.getJSON()` call is just calling a small list of words, a minimal extension of your example, also hosted on JSBin.

Note that before the JSON is successfully loaded, the function `words.random` is just a dummy function, which gets overridden once the words are in place.

But I still wonder, if you're only going to use this to load a single word, why you would bother to send the whole list down to the client.